# How to prohibit users from using pkexec?

Tags: permission-denied, pkexec

I can control which users can run `su` or `gksu` by, for example, including the line `auth       required   pam_wheel.so deny group=nosu` in `/etc/pam.d` – then members of group `nosu` won’t be able to use `su` or `gksu --su-mode`.

However, this won’t stop anyone from using `pkexec` (and it is futile to prohibit the use of `su` without prohibiting the use of `pkexec`, since apparently `pkexec` offers same functionality…). Is there any similar way to control who may and who may not use `pkexec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove all permissions for the group, nosu, using an ACL.

```
setfacl -m g:nosu:--- /usr/bin/pkexec
```

After setting the ACL, users who are not members of the nosu group still use `pkexec` normally.

Comment: Outta curiosity, I wonder if there is any configuration option of pkexec, PolicyKit that would disable it in a way similar to that line in pam.d though…